# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe098c09830

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

So I've seen and tried various countless changes to my code based on what i've seen on stackoverflow but literally nothing seems to work. The error is occuring when I press my volume button which will write to user default data so I can check that whenever audio is about to play during actual game play.

I think this is only my problem because i've tried everything. Anyway my code is below:

```
//if user presses volume button
@IBAction func DaVol(_ sender: Any)
{
    //if User default for audio is nil, initialize it, otherwise change it where needed
    if audioDefaultIsMuted.value(forKey: "Volume") != nil
    {
        //if the audio has been on turn it off
        let tempAudioDefaultIsMuted = audioDefaultIsMuted.value(forKey: "Volume") as! Bool
        if  tempAudioDefaultIsMuted == false
        {
            //if label is the on music one, set value to true (meaning ismuted will be true)
            //then change label to off label
            audioDefaultIsMuted.set(true, forKey: "Volume")
            audioDefaultIsMuted.synchronize()

            //change to new image
            volumectrl.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "nowaves"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise set value to false
            //then change label to on one
            audioDefaultIsMuted.set(true, forKey: "Volume")
            audioDefaultIsMuted.synchronize()

            //change to new image
            volumectrl.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "audio"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }
    let currVolImage = volumectrl.image(for: UIControlState.normal)
    //check curr image and do same shit as before accordingly
    if  currVolImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "audio")
    {
        //if label is the on music one, set value to true (meaning ismuted will be true)
        //then change label to off label
        audioDefaultIsMuted.set(true, forKey: "Volume")
        audioDefaultIsMuted.synchronize()

        volumectrl.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "nowaves"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
    else if currVolImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "nowaves")
    {
        //otherwise set value to false
        //then change label to on one
        audioDefaultIsMuted.set(false, forKey: "Volume")
        audioDefaultIsMuted.synchronize()

        volumectrl.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "audio"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to know the line that is causing the problem. In Xcode, do to the Breakpoints panel on the left, and add a new Exception breakpoint using the + button at the bottom. This will catch the exception as it is being thrown and you will be able to see which of your lines is causing the problem.

Comment: can you check the action connection plase

Comment: @insta catering check your storyboard has button connected properly and there are no more then 1 connection for same button .

Comment: Use breakpoints to understand crash further, which exact line causes crash.

Comment: Could please post your crash log and backtrace as well?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the audioDefaultIsMuted, and check its value.

You can use swift let if to simplify your code like this

```
if let value = audioDefaultIsMuted.value(forKey: "Volume") {
  print(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have connected button action to a method and after that you changed the method name or deleted the method and written and connected a new method.

Do this-

1. Right click on button in storyboard(if using) and delete all actions on it
2. Connect button action again by dragging from button to corresponding
   action method